# C++ write to csv, performance

Tags: c++, performance, csv

This is probably a simple question, but I have not been able to find specific information on this, or atleast information in a readable format. Most of the information I have found relates to reading data from a .csv.

I am have a function that have to save data to a .csv file. This is not an ideal format in a performance perspective, but let us assume that this cannot change. My data is stored in a **r x c x s** data structure and has to be outputed in the form **r,c,s,value** and saved to the .csv. At the moment i have:

```
char delimiter = ',';
ofstream ofs(file, ofstream::out);

for (int r = 0; r < P.n_rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < P.n_cols; c++)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < P.n_slices; s++)
        {
            ofs << r + 1 << delimiter << c + 1 << delimiter << s + 1 << delimiter << P(c, s, s) << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
ofs.close();
```

For a data structure of size 100 x 100 x 50 this take roughly 6 sec, which I fell is an necessary long time. I would much appreciate if you could provide some information on how to speed this up.

Comment: There must be a lot of csv writer libraries out there. Did you try any if it gave you better results? How big is `P`'s share of the runtime?

Comment: [First up, ditch `endl`. You really don't need to flush every line.](https://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/)

Comment: No I have not tried any csv libraries yet, but I will check it out to see if i find anything usefull.

Comment: Is this typo: `P(c, s, s)` (slice used twice) only in this post or in your code too?

Comment: Ohh I see, no it is just a type in the example above. It should be `P(r, c, s)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should note that [`endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is more than a newline - it actually *flushes* data to the disk.

> Inserts a newline character into the output sequence os and flushes it as if by calling os.put(os.widen('\n')) followed by os.flush().

This might slow down things considerably. You should try replacing it with a newline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, replacing `endl` with `\n` at the end helped to improve the prerformane in this specific case by a roughly 50-60 %.

Comment: You're very welcome. Good luck on making it even faster!

Comment: To go deeper why it's so much faster: flushing means sending data immediately to stream target, but writing to harddrives is VERY slow, so filestreams use buffering to collect data in RAM first and push bigger chunks fewer times. These chunks are even adjusted to sizes which are good for the harddrive. And even clearing a buffer may cost a bit. It's best to let the stream flush itself with full buffer and on close. Standard streams flush always because the user expects too see the data without further waiting.

Answer (score 3):

As was stated (and accepted) above, dropping `endl` reduces the time by 50-60% (in my case - from 7 seconds to 2 seconds, more than 70%).

However, there is still room for improvement: the general stream formatting. The following code further reduces run time by another 75%, to 500 ms:

```
int a[100][100][50];
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buff[64];
    memset(a, 1, 100 * 100 * 50 * sizeof(int));
    int count(0);
    char delimiter = ',';
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::ofstream ofs("test.csv", std::ofstream::out);
    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < 50; s++)
            {
                sprintf_s(buff, "%d,%d,%d,%d\n", r, c, s, a[c][r][s]);
                ofs << buff;
                //ofs << r + 1 << delimiter << c + 1 << delimiter << s + 1 << delimiter << a[c][r][s] << '\n';
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    ofs.close();
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms" << endl;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write to a stringstream first, then write it entirely to the output file:

```
char delimiter = ',';
stringstream ss;

for (int r = 0; r < P.n_rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < P.n_cols; c++)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < P.n_slices; s++)
        {
            ss << r + 1 << delimiter << c + 1 << delimiter << s + 1 << delimiter << P(r, c, s) << endl;
        }
    }
}
ofstream ofs(file, ofstream::out);
ofs << ss.str();
ofs.close();
```

Actually replacing endl with "\n" solves the problem already:

```
char delimiter = ',';
ofstream ofs(file, ofstream::out);

for (int r = 0; r < P.n_rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < P.n_cols; c++)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < P.n_slices; s++)
        {
            ofs << r + 1 << delimiter << c + 1 << delimiter << s + 1 << delimiter << P(r, c, s) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
ofs.close();
```

This gives about 2X speed up on my machine:

```
string delimiter = ",";
string ss;
ss.reserve(P.n_rows * P.n_cols * P.n_slices * 20);

int max_idx = max(P.n_rows, max(P.n_cols, P.n_slices));
vector<string> idx_str(max_idx);
for(int i=0;i<max_idx;++i) idx_str[i] = std::to_string(i+1);

for (int r = 0; r < P.n_rows; r++)
{
  auto& rstr = idx_str[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < P.n_cols; c++)
    {
      auto& cstr = idx_str[c];
      string thisline = rstr + delimiter + cstr + delimiter;

        for (int s = 0; s < P.n_slices; s++)
        {
          auto& sstr = idx_str[s];
            ss += thisline
                + sstr + delimiter
                + std::to_string(data[r][c][s]) + "\n";
        }
    }
}
ofstream ofs(file, ofstream::out);
ofs.write(ss.c_str(), sizeof(char)*ss.size());
ofs.close();
```

Comment: What makes you think this would be faster? (Not necessarily disagreeing, but a good answer should explain, and include some evidence). There's a lot more allocation overhead. Also, why are you using `std::stringstream` not `std::ostringstream`, and why are you flushing it, that does nothing useful at all?

Comment: Basically just aggregating lots of disk IO operations into a single one. In my experience, could be 5X to 10X faster.

Comment: A good point, which should be part of the answer, not a comment. And also, solved much more simply by simply removing the superfluous flushes in the original.

Comment: flushing is just to keep the same output format as the original code.

Comment: But the flushing is the problem in the first place! (Probably)

Comment: You are right... Replace endl with "\n" solves the problem already. I've also tried mmap before, could be slightly faster.

Comment: I tried this, but with only limited success. Im not sure why, since this seems like a reasonable argument.

Comment: Well, replacing endl with "\n" is close to the limit of this approach (using c++ streams). If you need even faster speed, you may want to consider messing with raw buffer directly, if you don't have to stick with csv file format.